# VS Code Prettier formatting Typescript incorrectly

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

In my code, I want to write:

```
const [state, setState] = useState<string>(undefined);
```

However, VS Code with Prettier auto formats it as:

```
const [state, setState] = useState < string > undefined;
```

Is there a setting in VS Code and/or Prettier I can use to make this behave as I want it to?

VS Code `settings.json`

```
{
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "activityBar.activeBackground": "#65c89b",
    "activityBar.activeBorder": "#945bc4",
    "activityBar.background": "#65c89b",
    "activityBar.foreground": "#15202b",
    "activityBar.inactiveForeground": "#15202b99",
    "activityBarBadge.background": "#945bc4",
    "activityBarBadge.foreground": "#e7e7e7",
    "sash.hoverBorder": "#65c89b",
    "statusBar.background": "#42b883",
    "statusBar.foreground": "#15202b",
    "statusBarItem.hoverBackground": "#359268",
    "statusBarItem.remoteBackground": "#42b883",
    "statusBarItem.remoteForeground": "#15202b",
    "titleBar.activeBackground": "#42b883",
    "titleBar.activeForeground": "#15202b",
    "titleBar.inactiveBackground": "#42b88399",
    "titleBar.inactiveForeground": "#15202b99"
  },
  "peacock.color": "#42b883",
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a conflict with some other formatter or extension you have installed. Have you tried replicating this with default settings and no other extensions active?

Comment: It sounds like Prettier is treating TypeScript as JS for some reason.

Comment: @Etheryte good shout, just checked, it's Prettier.

Comment: did you try the default VS Code formatter?? Use this - ```"[typescript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
    }```

Comment: @DusayantaPrasad that works but doesn't do the rest of what Prettier does

Comment: Did you follow [the installation instructions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode)? I can't replicate this problem on a fresh VSCode with Prettier. It would be helpful if you included your `settings.json` for VSCode.

Comment: @Etheryte added settings.json

Comment: Thanks for the updated info, sadly I still can't replicate the issue. If it's not private, could you perhaps share the whole project on a-la Github or similar?